# Jquery mouseenter cant' see when out from span to fire again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I have something like this

```
<div id='one'>xyz
  <span id='two'>abc</span>
</div>
```

I want to be able to hover element `one`, then element `two` then `one` again
but jquery can't recognize the when i'm leaving `two`, im actually re-entering `one` 
I need/expect to be able to fire an event when i'm re-entering one

Is it possible to achieve this without modifying the html markup of the page (I can't touch it!)

Comment: Please add complete code.

Answer (score 0):

I think below code is helpful to you

```css
#one{
width:100px;
height:100px;
position:relative
}
#one:hover{
width:150px;
height:160px;
background-color:red;
}
#two{
width:100%;
position:absolute;
height:100px;
}
#two:hover{
width:100px;
background-color:green;
height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id='one'>xyz
  <span id='two'>abc</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following:

```js
$('div#two').bind(('mouseenter, mouseleave'), function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$('body').on('mouseenter', '#one', function(e){
  console.log('You entered: ', $(this).attr('id'));
}).on('mouseleave', '#one', function(){
  console.log('You left: ', $(this).attr('id'));
});

$('body').on('mouseenter', '#two', function(){
  console.log('You entered: ', $(this).attr('id'));
}).on('mouseleave', '#two', function(){
  console.log('You left: ', $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```css
#one{
  background-color: red;
}
#two{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='one'>xyz
  <span id='two'>abc</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you enter two you actually never leave one, because two is inside one only. So, mouseenter event of one will never get triggered when you enter its' descendants.

You can probably distinguish it, by attaching mouseenter event on all the descendants of one, to track mouseleave from one, alongwith mouseleave event on one

```
$("#one").mouseenter(function(){
   //Entering one
});

$("#one").children().mouseleave(function(){
   //Entering one again
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when mouse is in `#two` or `#one` ,it has just `mouseenter` event,because mouse don't leave `#one`.

**Try this:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#two').hover(function(){
    $('#one').toggleClass('newCss');
  },function(){
    $('#one').toggleClass('newCss');
  })

  $('#one').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('newCss');
  })

})
```

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#two').hover(function(){
      $('#one').toggleClass('newCss');
    },function(){
      $('#one').toggleClass('newCss');
    })
    
    $('#one').hover(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('newCss');
    })
  })
```

```css
#one {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}

#two {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 30px;
}

#two:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
    
.newCss {
  background-color: green!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='one'>xyz
  <span id='two'>abc</span>
</div>
```